# Making the texture brush snap to the surface and lower distortion on stroke

Tags: texturing, snapping

I've been searching for some kind of option or addon for making the texture brush snap or slide across my mesh to make any lines made equal in size/thickness, but it seems like I just can't find the option, if it exists. Top view looks good, since it was the angle I painted it from, but looking at it from a different angle is distorted. I am using Blender 2.92 if that helps. I added a second image to help explain better. Just a simple circle, but when moving the camera angle up it reveals that it basically projected the shape, creating a tear drop shape
[image: Top view looks good, but a side view looks distorted.]

[image: 2nd]

Comment: Try creating a hexagon in an external app, export it as e.g. a jpg file and map it in Blender.

Comment: It's not the shape I'm trying to accomplish though, it's keeping the lines that same thickness when using the line option in texture paint mod. This character has more complex markings than this. Using other brush tools also have the same problem, where it looks stretched and distorted at different angles.

Comment: See if it looks the same in orthographic camera as this may be caused by perspective.